# How can I load a json database file with references in PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I decode a json database file that contains references to other json files using PHP? The goal is to get a single object with all references loaded.

Example of a json database file with references:

```
{
  "id": 12, 
  "title": "Credit card number disclosure", 
  "severity": "medium", 
  "description": {
    "$ref": "#/files/description/12"
  }, 
  "fix": {
    "effort": 50, 
    "guidance": {
      "$ref": "#/files/fix/57"
    }
  }, 
  "cwe": [
    "200"
  ], 
  "references": [
    {
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm", 
      "title": "Wikipedia - Luhn algorithm"
    }, 
    {
      "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number", 
      "title": "Wikipedia - Bank card number"
    }
  ]
}
```

`file_get_contents()` with a `json_decode()` will not automatically load the references.

Comment: do you wan to load those references are those in json format?

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?PHP

$json_file = file_get_contents("db.json");
$json = json_decode($json_file);

function walkObject($obj) {
    foreach($obj as $prop => $value) {
        if (is_object($value))
            $obj->$prop = walkObject($value);

        if ($prop == "\$ref") 
            $obj->$prop = walkObject(json_decode(file_get_contents($value)));

    }

    return $obj;
}
```

This will load your initial json file, decode it and walk over it recursively. Every time it sees a $ref property - it will try to read the file it points to decode it and walk over it recursively...

You should implement checks for errors for file_get_contents and json_decode..